# Facepile shows a white box with an option to switch when user selects "Use Facebook as:" option from her facebook account

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-fbml

I have facepile plugin on my webpage to show faces who are using the application.
The code snippet to show facepile is

```
<fb:facepile id="some_id" data-size="medium" data-width="396">
</fb:facepile>
```

Faces are showing normally.But when I use "Use facebook as:" option from the facebook homepage and selects any of my listed pages, facepile plugin on my webpage turns weird and shows a white box with a small thumbnail and an anchor(with text 'switch') on top of it  On inspecting element with chrome's right click context menu I found it's an iframe with width being 396px and height being 1000px which displays in the middle of page hiding html form for normal login too.
If I revert to my profile using "Use facebook as:" option faces start showing normally.
Am I missing something or It's a bug?

I already checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290069/facepile-iframe-is-white-when-the-viewer-is-not-logged-in-to-facebook) but that is related to user being not logged.

Also I checked this [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/312418878851638) listed
on facebook developer page but it seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour, although obviously the error message should be a bit better - the Facepile (and indeed, most of the Social Plugins) is designed to only work with User accounts. You can be fairly sure that 99.9% of people viewing the plugins will not be "Using Facebook as" a Page.

As Pages aren't designed to really interact with Facebook APIs (beyond the `manage_pages` functionality) then it is likely that these plugins won't be fixed to work for page accounts, but they'd be fixed to show a message informing anyone logged in as a Page to switch back to their user account.

You can find some related bug reports below, you should consider adding your voice to them in order to increase their priority:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/372904202778489
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/313164415437524